# EclipseでMavenのプロジェクト作成が失敗してしまいます．

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Eclipseは使ったことがありますが、Mavenはまったく初めてでプロジェクト作成でエラーになっても手掛かりがわかりません．すみませんが対処方法を教えてください．

以下のURLに載せられた方法に従っています．

[Creating a Startup Project from the Eclipse IDE](https://www.oxygenxml.com/oxygen_sdk/download.html)

1. Eclipseのダウンロード
   [Eclipse IDE 2020‑06](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) をダウンロードして、Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developerをインストール．
2. C:\Users<YOUR_USER_NAME>.m2\settings.xmlをセットアップ
3. Validation Optionページで、Suspend all validators を設定
4. File/New Maven Projectより、
   [image: Add Archetype]を設定
5. New Maven Projectで以下の通り設定
   [image: Group Id, Artifact Idを設定]
6. ところがFinishで以下のエラーとなります．
   [image: エラーダイアログ]

エラーメッセージのテキストは以下の通りです．

> Could not resolve archetype com.oxygenxml.samples:oxygen-sdk-samples-archetype:21.1.0.2 from any of the configured repositories.
> Could not resolve artifact com.oxygenxml.samples:oxygen-sdk-samples-archetype:pom:21.1.0.2
> Missing com.oxygenxml.samples:oxygen-sdk-samples-archetype:pom:21.1.0.2

以上 初心者の質問ですみませんがよろしくお願いいたします．不足の情報がありましたらご指摘ください．

(06/10追加)
Windowsの以下の箇所にはリポジトリと思しきものが正常に作られております．

[image: リポジトリフォルダ]

(06/11追加)
以下の出羽さんの回答で`Default Local`を選択した箇所は以下の通りです．

[image: Default Local選択箇所]

以下のようにプロジェクトを開けました．

[image: プロジェクトエクスプローラの画面]

Comment: ログインが必要なようなのでリンク先は見られませんが、 `https://www.oxygenxml.com/maven/` ではないですか？(httpでなくhttps) https://www.oxygenxml.com/maven/com/oxygenxml/samples/oxygen-sdk-samples-archetype/21.1.0.2/

Comment: ログインが必要な点言及していませんでした．すみません．C:\Users<YOUR_USER_NAME>.m2\settings.xml にはご指摘のとおりhttpでなくhttpsも指定して試しておりますが、同じ結果になってしまいます．

Comment: 参考: 関連するかもしれない英語版での質問 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/44970149

Comment: また英語版Stackoverflowでの関連する質問の、一つ前のバージョンをインストールしていては当たっています．私も2020-06の1つ前の2020-03をインストールしています．ただこちらは、重要なプロジェクト構築で使用しているので、回答にあるような`.m2`や`.eclipse`の削除は恐ろしくてできません．ちなみに2020-03で同じ手順でmavenプロジェクトを作成してみましたが、結果は上記で報告したものと全く同じでした．

Comment: 実際に削除するのではなく、一時的にリネームなどで退避しておくのも一つの方法かと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手順4.を行った際の親ダイアログでCatalogを選択する箇所があると思いますが、`Default Local`を選択する必要があるようです。

何もしないと`Nexus Indexer`(これが何を意味するのか私には分かりません)の方が選ばれるようですが、こちらを選ぶと私の環境でも質問に記載されているエラーが発生しました。
(ちなみにリンク先のログインが必要なページの内容は見られていないので`settings.xml`は何も変更していません)

Comment: 御指摘のとおり、`Default Local`を選択することでプロジェクトが作成できました．結果は質問に追記してあります．どうもありがとうございました．